# Alter table add column with data populated from another column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to add a column to a table which needs to take a varchar value from an existing column in the table and convert it into an int in an if/then format.

example:

```
if size = d then size_int = 1
else if size = f then size_int = 2
else if size = t then size_int = 3
else if size = s then size_int = 4
else if size = m then size_int = 5
else if size = l then size_int = 6
else if size = h then size_int = 7
else if size = g then size_int = 8
else if size = c then size_int = 9
```

If there is an easier way to do this by first adding the column then altering it that would work too.

Comment: If those two columns are going to retain that relationship, you're breaking normal form (and storing derived data) with this layout.  It would be preferable to derive the size_int in a VIEW or store the size to size_int mappings in a lookup table.

Comment: Wow, edited by none other than the Coding Horror himself.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE <YOUR_TABLE> ADD size_int INT;
UPDATE <YOUR_TABLE> SET size_int = 
CASE size 
    WHEN 'd' THEN 1
    WHEN 'f' THEN 2
    WHEN 't' THEN 3
    WHEN 's' THEN 4
    WHEN 'm' THEN 5
    WHEN 'l' THEN 6
    WHEN 'h' THEN 7
    WHEN 'g' THEN 8
    WHEN 'c' THEN 9
    ELSE NULL
END
```

Comment: the purpose of the derived data was simply to do a quick update to the table then drop the size col and continue forward using only size_int.  i thought this would be the easiest way to do it in order to write a select statement to return the sizes within a range i.e. =3, or between 4 and 6, <5 etc.